# Does the jakarta persistence API support org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, neo4j-ogm, hibernate-ogm

I am using hibernate-ogm-neo4j(v.5.4.1.Final) and I have setup a persistence.xml with `org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence` provider. When I tried to instantiate an EntityManagerFactory from the jakarta persistence API 3.0 I received this error: `jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named <persistence_unit_name>`.

So my question here is: Does the `hibernate-ogm-*` supports jakarta 3.0 implementation to be able to create an EntityManager for that provider: `HibernateOgmPersistence`?

Thanks.

Comment: Hibernate OGM is not maintained for years. The latest version is same (5.4.1.Final). And this version is reached end-of-life.

Comment: @zforgo, Yes, I know that OBG is not maintained for years, but I thought that there is a workaround for that, or I did something wrong.

Comment: I am eagerly awaiting Jakarta EE 11, which includes support for NoSQL, enabling me to eliminate Hibernate OGM and migrate the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

I'd migrated from 'Hibernate OGM' to Morphia:

[morphia.dev/morphia/2.3/quicktour.html](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.3/quicktour.html)

I wrote a small piece on my website:

[notify.co.uk/code-from-two-islands](https://notify.co.uk/code-from-two-islands)